# unknown revision error when trying to pull repository from hg

Tags: mercurial, repository, pull

I am trying to clone a repo from Mercurial. I entered the command: `hg pull --rev=2500`, it works.

However, when I try `hg pull --rev 3000`, it shows error: `abort:unknown revision '3000'`!

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks,
Jennifer.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to drop the `--revision=number` part.  But there's something odd here: `hg pull` is meant for *copying changesets from* a repository, not for *cloning* a repository.

To *clone* a repository means:

1. Make a new, empty repository.
2. Copy all<sup>1</sup> the changesets from some other repository to this repository.

To *pull from* a repository means:

1. Copy all<sup>2</sup> the changesets from some other repostory, that they have and I don't, to this repository.

Note how these two are similar but not identical.  The clone operation first makes a new, empty repository.  Step 2, fill the repository with (all) changesets from the other repository, matches step 1 of the *pull* action.  With a pull, we add only the changesets that they have that we don't, but since our new empty repository is *empty*, *all* changesets they have are ones that we don't.

Both operations involve calling up some *other* (existing) Mercurial repository.  The first one creates your repository while it makes this call; the second uses your existing repository, and makes this call.  Note that in both cases, the other repository here has its own changesets, which are on some set of branches, and that other repository numbers those changesets using *its* numbering.

Since you already have a repository, you apparently just want `hg pull` anyway.  See footnotes 1 and 2 for what the `--rev=2500` is doing.

---

<sup>1</sup>Sometimes we don't need *all* of the changesets.  We can make a limited clone using only *some* of the changesets.  Cloning with `-b branch` tells Mercurial to omit changesets not required to obtain the changesets that are on the named branch.

<sup>2</sup>As before, we might not need *all* changesets.  We can tell the other Mercurial repository: *Give me your changesets ending with your number 2500*, for instance.  You're asking it for its changesets up to number 3000, and it simply does not have that many changesets at this point.

Comment: Hi Torek, I use --rev becuase the repo is too big, I need to clone it part by part. I can't use hg clone directly.

Comment: The best thing to do is to fix the underlying issue that makes the direct clone fail, but as a workaround, you can use the `-r` method, you just need to pick a smaller number than 3000. We don't know how small: we know it's greater than or equal to 2500 and less than 3000, but that leaves 500 possible values. At this point, perhaps you can just omit it anyway: the `hg pull` operation will find that you already have the first 2500 changesets and not bring them over again.